# excel / open office - append an incrementing value to all non-unique fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, sql, worksheet-function, query

I have a large table of about 7500 store names. I need to search through those names and, if they are not unique, append an incrementing value, for example:

store_1
store_2

etc.

Anyone know how to do this?

For another project, I was using this:

=J1&IF(COUNTIF($J$1:J1,J1)>1,COUNTIF($J$1:J1,J1),"")

but in open office this gives an error, and in google spreadsheets, it times out because my database is so big. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using [LibreOffice 3.6.3](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) (a mild fork of OpenOffice), I was able to get this to work just by changing "J" to "A" in your formula and inputting data in column A such as "John, Joe, John, Joe" -- the second occurrence has a "2" at the end, the third occurrence of each datum has a "3" at the end, and so on.

What error specifically do you get, and which version of OpenOffice are you using?